# spring-boot security login failed

Tags: java, security, session, spring-boot

I made one spring-boot security demo，it just a simply login verify，
it's startup successful , can login and use all function.but I can't login when I share session by redis.

I find spring security put the `SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper` to session with the session key 'SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT' when login success .

It's a spring class and did't serialized,I don't know how to fix this problem.

please help me ,thinks

Error log：

```
20:25:17.629 [http-nio-8099-exec-6] ERROR o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/login] due to exception [Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper]
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:171)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:86)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:770)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:662)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:388)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have put a non-serializable object into a request's `HttpSession` object, and Redis session repository can't handle it.

The problematic class is:

org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper

... which is a strange object to put into a `HttpSession` object.

You need to figure out why you are (apparently) putting an `HttpSession` inside another `HttpSession`, and then fix it.  (You can't do that in this case because `HttpSessionWrapper` is not serializable ...)

Comment: Thanks very much,I find spring security put the SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper to session with the session key 'SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT' when login success .bug I still can't fix the problem